# What is the equation to determine an element's index in a jagged array given it's index from the equivalent flattened array?

Tags: functions, algorithms, dynamic-programming

If one has a jagged array of `N` dimensions and an index of an element in the flattened representation of that array, is there an equation that would retrieve the index of that element in the original, jagged array?

Example:

Assume the `jagged_array` is:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3].
 [4, 5],
 [6]
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

The element `7` has an index of `jagged_array_flattened[7]`. If I have it's position in the flattened array, how can I get it's position in the original array (it would be `jagged_array[3][0]`.

Would be cool if it did not matter how many dimensions you had, but I am mostly dealing with 2D arrays. If there is no equation, perhaps some pseudocode?

Thanks.

Edit: I feel like the N-dimensions makes it too difficult to generalize, so unless I am wrong, perhaps the focus should be on 2D arrays.

Edit 2: Here is a quick write up of my solution in code.

```
function getValue(list, flattenedIndex) {
    let firstIndexOfSubList = 0;
    let lastIndexOfSubList = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        lastIndexOfSubList += list[i].length - 1;
        if (lastIndexOfSubList === flattenedIndex) return list[i][lastIndexOfSubList - firstIndexOfSubList];
        else if (Math.max(flattenedIndex, lastIndexOfSubList) === flattenedIndex) {
            lastIndexOfSubList++;
            firstIndexOfSubList = lastIndexOfSubList;
        } else return list[i][flattenedIndex - firstIndexOfSubList];
    }
}
```

Edit 2: A solution with binary search *if* you have a precomputed list of lengths:

````
function binaryWhatever(jsonb, flattenedIndex) {
    let lo = 0;
    let hi = jsonb.length

    while (lo < hi) {
        let mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
        if (flattenedIndex < jsonb[mid]) hi = mid;
        else lo = mid + 1;
    }
    let index1 = lo - 1;
    let index2 = flattenedIndex - jsonb[lo - 1];

    return [index1, index2]
}
```
````

Comment: Just think how **you** would do it **manually but systematically**, and implement **that** method in your desired program.

Comment: @user21820 I have an algorithm that works, but I suspect there might be something better, so I want to see what the community thinks. Never fail to see some true genius on here.

Comment: Ok please put your algorithm into your question so that it doesn't seem as if you're just out-sourcing homework. After you've done so, ping me again and I'll have a look. There are more efficient ways but before we get to that I want to see that you know how to do the easy way first.

Comment: @user21820 edited to include some snippet. not really thought out, was wondering if there is something better. There might be some interesting math solution.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Your code has mismatched brackets. Also do take note that Math SE is about the mathematics so it is better if you wrote pseudo-code that everyone understands than using language-specific syntax such as "for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)". There are also other errors. In any case, it seems that your algorithm won't work even after the errors are fixed, so do test out your algorithm before editing your post again to fix it.

Comment: @user21820 yeah thanks for catching that, just wrote it real quick. I've tested it out thoroughly; looks fine to me? Can you lmk why it's incorrect? Again this only works for 2D arrays for now

Comment: @user21820 what are you talking about? I don't have a variable called `first`. If you are on mobile, try scrolling to the right? I think it's getting cut off.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t61sw09e/ (I changed nothing except closing the array in this)

Comment: Sorry about my mistaken claim of an undefined variable `first`. I really did not realize it was cut off! I have deleted my irrelevant comments and have posted an answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt can be improved slightly by combining the first and third cases together:

> `if (lastIndexOfSubList >= flattenedIndex) return list[i][lastIndexOfSubList - firstIndexOfSubList];`

Note that if you only want to perform this conversion operation *once*, then you cannot do better than such a linear for-loop because you at least have to read the lengths of all the sublists up to the point where the answer is.

However, if you want to perform this conversion *multiple times*, then there is in fact a much more efficient way. To understand it, you will have to learn and understand binary search. The gist of the efficient solution is that you precompute the total length of the first $k$ sublists, for each $k$ from $1$ to `list.length`. Then you binary search that precomputed array (of cumulative lengths) to find the sublist in which the answer lies. And then you can extract the answer easily from there.

Have a try first and let me know in the comments if you need further help!

Comment: Good catch with that if-statement! 
If I understand what you're syaing about binary search; make a binary tree, each element is `lastIndexOfSublist+= lastIndexOfSublist`? So, if I have five lists of lengths 10, 20, 30, 40, 50; the resulting array would be [10, 30, 60, 100, 150]. Then I take my flattened index and find what two indices it is between, right? I like it.

Comment: @JohnLexus: You don't have to make a binary tree. Binary search can be done on a linear array in a straightforward manner. Of course, if you just want to make a binary tree for the fun of it, you can. Yes, your precomputed array is correct.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean a binary tree - meant a sorted array. Good stuff, will write it and show it to you when I get the chance

Comment: @JohnLexus: Sure! Afterward, if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it. If you wish to continue inquiries about this or more generic algorithmic methods, feel free to ping me [in this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161/basic-mathematics).

Comment: I updated my answer with my solution. See if you like it

Comment: @JohnLexus: Uh I'm too lazy to carefully prove that your solution works, so I'll leave that to you! By the way, on Math SE it's convention not to significantly update your question in a way that makes earlier answers no longer seem to be answering. It doesn't matter here because I'm the only answerer so I know what's going on, but next time you should consider simply posting your own answer to demonstrate what you have learnt (including from other answers).

Comment: @JohnLexus: One more comment. Binary search is in some sense optimal per query, because you need to output $Ω(\log(c))$ bits where $c$ is the number of sublists, and binary search achieves that. So that's indeed the best you can do.